# Packages tableof and paracol: multiple tables of content don't work

Tags: table-of-contents, paracol

I am writing a large document in two languages (german in the left column, english in the right) using paracol. Now, after the first ~100 pages, I'm trying to create a Table of Contents also in two columns (german - english) and I thought that package tableof could help here, but it doesn't. I'm kind of confused ... maybe somebody can help me?

Here is an example code - I cannot show the original one since it contains company know-how, and I think that all the included packages are necessary.

Chapters and sections are tagged b (both), d (german) and e (english).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,parskip]{scrreprt}  
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}  
\usepackage{selinput}  
\SelectInputMappings{adieresis={ä},germanbls={ß},}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{tabularx}  
\usepackage{geometry}  
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage[right]{eurosym} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}  
\usepackage{colortbl}  
\usepackage{paralist}  
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage{parskip}  
\usepackage{picins}  
\usepackage[subfigure,titles]{tocloft}  
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels=true, colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}  
\usepackage{nomencl}  
\makenomenclature  
\usepackage{makeidx}  
\makeindex  
\usepackage{natbib}  
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{bm}  
\usepackage{float}  
\usepackage{pdfpages}  
\usepackage{longtable}  
\usepackage{csquotes}  
\usepackage{mdwtab, tabularx}  
\usepackage{lastpage}  
\usepackage[super]{nth}  
\usepackage{paracol}  
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,diagbox,multirow}  
\usepackage{enumitem}  
\usepackage{caption}  
\usepackage[lang=english,font=it]{bicaption}  
\usepackage[format=hang]{subcaption}  
\pagestyle{fancy}  
\fancyhf{}  
\usepackage{marginnote}  
\usepackage{eso-pic}  
\usepackage{watermark}  
\usepackage{tableof}  
\AtBeginDocument{\tofOpenTocFileForWrite}  

\begin{document}  
\bibliographystyle{plain}  
\pagestyle{fancy}  
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}  
\fancyhf{}  
%  
\part{Erster Teil\\ First Part}  
\tableof{b}   
\tableof{d}  
\tableof{e}  
%  
\toftagthis{b}  
\chapter{Das erste Kapitel \\ The first chapter}  
\begin{sloppypar}  
\begin{paracol}{2}  
\begin{leftcolumn}  
Ein bißchen deutscher Text, der das erste Kapitel einleitet, bevor es mit dem ersten Abschnitt losgeht.  
\end{leftcolumn}  
\begin{rightcolumn}  
A little bit of english text supposed to prepare the reader for the first section.  
\end{rightcolumn}  
%  
\begin{leftcolumn}  
\toftagthis{d}  
\section{Der erste Abschnitt im ersten Kapitel}  
Der Text zum ersten Abschnitt.  
\end{leftcolumn}  
\begin{rightcolumn}  
\toftagthis{e}  
\section{The first section of the first chapter}  
Text in the first section.  
\end{rightcolumn}  
%  
\begin{leftcolumn}  
\toftagthis{d}  
\section{Der zweite Abschnitt im ersten Kapitel}  
Text im zweiten Abschnitt.  
\end{leftcolumn}  
\begin{rightcolumn}  
\toftagthis{e}  
\section{The second section in the first chapter}  
Text belonging to the second section.  
\end{rightcolumn}  
\end{paracol}  
\end{sloppypar}  
%  
\toftagthis{b}  
\chapter{Das zweite Kapitel \\ The second chapter}  
\begin{sloppypar}  
\begin{paracol}{2}  
\begin{leftcolumn}  
\toftagthis{d}  
\section{Der erste Abschnitt im zweiten Kapitel}  
Das zweite Kapitel beginnt mit diesem Abschnitt.  
\end{leftcolumn}  
\begin{rightcolumn}  
\toftagthis{e}  
\section{The first section of the second chapter}  
The second chapter starts with this section.  
\end{rightcolumn}  
\end{paracol}  
\end{sloppypar}  
\end{document}
```

The pdf shows only the first (b) table of Contents, whatever I try.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui. Also, when asking questions rather than posting large chunks of code, as you have done, it is better if you can reduce your code to a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) because this makes it easier for people to help you -- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! And nice nickname. :D

Comment: All tocs are there you just can't see them. Try `\tableof{b} \hrule  
\tableof{d}  \hrule
\tableof{e}  \hrule`

Comment: [Crosspost](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=28509&p=96555#p96555) and [Crosspost](http://golatex.de/viewtopic,p,86883.html#86883)

Comment: I said it is ok to crosspost, as long as you provide the links. These are the rules of LaTeX-community and goLaTeX, because it is the way nettiquette works.

Comment: Dear Johannes, I have a problem answering in the german forum. I also tried to send you a private mail but even this don't work today. Sorry for the confusion, I'd rather close down the thread in the german forum because I first want to test all the solutions proposed in this forum (many thanks to all!).

Answer (score 4):

Your example is very far from being a minimal one and as a result the formulation of your question may be misleading. Something *else* than `tableof` and `paracol` is causing a problem (a serious one indeed as during testing I often ended in staled LaTeX compilations). Here it works:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,parskip]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{tableof}
\AtBeginDocument{\tofOpenTocFileForWrite}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\fancyhf{}
%
\part{Erster Teil\\ First Part}
\tableof{b}

\vspace{3ex}
\hrule height 1pt
\vspace{3ex}

\begin{paracol}2
  \begin{leftcolumn}
    \centerline{\textbf{Deutsch}}
    \tableof{d}
  \end{leftcolumn}
  \begin{rightcolumn}
    \centerline{\textbf{English}}
    \tableof{e}
  \end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}
%
\toftagstart{b}
\chapter{Das erste Kapitel \\ The first chapter}
\begin{sloppypar}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{leftcolumn}
Ein bißchen deutscher Text, der das erste Kapitel einleitet, bevor es mit dem
ersten Abschnitt losgeht.
\end{leftcolumn}
\begin{rightcolumn}
A little bit of english text supposed to prepare the reader for the first section.
\end{rightcolumn}
%
\begin{leftcolumn}
\toftagthis{d}
\section{Der erste Abschnitt im ersten Kapitel}
Der Text zum ersten Abschnitt.
\end{leftcolumn}
\begin{rightcolumn}
\toftagthis{e}
\section{The first section of the first chapter}
Text in the first section.
\end{rightcolumn}
%
\begin{leftcolumn}
\toftagthis{d}
\section{Der zweite Abschnitt im ersten Kapitel}
Text im zweiten Abschnitt.
\end{leftcolumn}
\begin{rightcolumn}
\toftagthis{e}
\section{The second section in the first chapter}
Text belonging to the second section.
\end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}
\end{sloppypar}
% you can try this:
% \toftagthis{d,e}
\chapter{Das zweite Kapitel \\ The second chapter}
\begin{sloppypar}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{leftcolumn}
\toftagthis{d}
\section{Der erste Abschnitt im zweiten Kapitel}
Das zweite Kapitel beginnt mit diesem Abschnitt.
\end{leftcolumn}
\begin{rightcolumn}
\toftagthis{e}
\section{The first section of the second chapter}
The second chapter starts with this section.
\end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now the culprit is among the things I commented out:

```
% \usepackage{selinput}
% \SelectInputMappings{adieresis={ä},germanbls={ß},}
% \usepackage{amsmath}
% \usepackage{amsfonts}
% \usepackage{amssymb}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{tabularx}
% \usepackage{geometry}
% \usepackage{setspace}
% \usepackage[right]{eurosym}
% \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
% \usepackage{colortbl}
% \usepackage{paralist}
% \usepackage{booktabs}
% \usepackage{array}
% \usepackage{parskip}
% %\usepackage{picins}
% %\usepackage[subfigure,titles]{tocloft}
% \usepackage[pdfpagelabels=true, colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
% \usepackage{nomencl}
% \makenomenclature
% \usepackage{makeidx}
% \makeindex
% \usepackage{natbib}
% \usepackage{multirow}
% \usepackage{bm}
% \usepackage{float}
% \usepackage{pdfpages}
% \usepackage{longtable}
% \usepackage{csquotes}
% \usepackage{mdwtab, tabularx}
% \usepackage{lastpage}
% \usepackage[super]{nth}
% \usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
% \usepackage{fancyhdr}
% \usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,diagbox,multirow}
% \usepackage{enumitem}
% \usepackage{caption}
% \usepackage[lang=english,font=it]{bicaption}
% \usepackage[format=hang]{subcaption}
% \pagestyle{fancy}
% \fancyhf{}
% \usepackage{marginnote}
% \usepackage{eso-pic}
% \usepackage{watermark}
```

Proceed by dichotomy to identify the package(s) which badly interact.

---

## edit

some change of ordering of the packages makes your mwe compile:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,parskip]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{tableof}
\AtBeginDocument{\tofOpenTocFileForWrite}

\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{adieresis={ä},germanbls={ß},}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{parskip}
%\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage[subfigure,titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels=true, colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex


\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{mdwtab, tabularx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,diagbox,multirow}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[lang=english,font=it]{bicaption}
\usepackage[format=hang]{subcaption}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{watermark}


\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\fancyhf{}
%
\part{Erster Teil\\ First Part}
\tableof{b}

\vspace{3ex}
\hrule height 1pt
\vspace{3ex}

\begin{paracol}2
  \begin{leftcolumn}
    \centerline{\textbf{Deutsch}}
    \tableof{d}
  \end{leftcolumn}
  \begin{rightcolumn}
    \centerline{\textbf{English}}
    \tableof{e}
  \end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}
%
\toftagstart{b}
\chapter{Das erste Kapitel \\ The first chapter}
\begin{sloppypar}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{leftcolumn}
Ein bißchen deutscher Text, der das erste Kapitel einleitet, bevor es mit dem
ersten Abschnitt losgeht.
\end{leftcolumn}
\begin{rightcolumn}
A little bit of english text supposed to prepare the reader for the first section.
\end{rightcolumn}
%
\begin{leftcolumn}
\toftagthis{d}
\section{Der erste Abschnitt im ersten Kapitel}
Der Text zum ersten Abschnitt.
\end{leftcolumn}
\begin{rightcolumn}
\toftagthis{e}
\section{The first section of the first chapter}
Text in the first section.
\end{rightcolumn}
%
\begin{leftcolumn}
\toftagthis{d}
\section{Der zweite Abschnitt im ersten Kapitel}
Text im zweiten Abschnitt.
\end{leftcolumn}
\begin{rightcolumn}
\toftagthis{e}
\section{The second section in the first chapter}
Text belonging to the second section.
\end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}
\end{sloppypar}
% you can try this:
% \toftagthis{d,e}
\chapter{Das zweite Kapitel \\ The second chapter}
\begin{sloppypar}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{leftcolumn}
\toftagthis{d}
\section{Der erste Abschnitt im zweiten Kapitel}
Das zweite Kapitel beginnt mit diesem Abschnitt.
\end{leftcolumn}
\begin{rightcolumn}
\toftagthis{e}
\section{The first section of the second chapter}
The second chapter starts with this section.
\end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

No idea why. `picins` is commented-out as it does not exist on my installation.

Comment: The comments to the question contain links to a crosspost to LC, where Clemens also tried to figure out the problem.

Comment: jfbu's solution works perfectly, many thanks! So the question is answered, we can close the topic and all related ones in two other forums.

Comment: @tableofconfusion interesting: yesterday you told me this solution wouldn't work in your real life document!

Comment: Sorry, Clemens, maybe it's because I am working on different computers (office and private). I also have changed and discarded a lot in my preamble, after all I'm glad that it's working now.