# Package paracol: no chapters allowed?

Tags: chapters, paracol

today I have a question regarding the **paracol** package which is somewhat related to the one I have recently asked, [Packages tableof and paracol: multiple tables of content don't work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330200/packages-tableof-and-paracol-multiple-tables-of-content-dont-work), but it is more about **paracol** than about **tableof**.

**It seems like paracol doesn't like Chapters.** When I only put sections in the paracol environment, everything works fine (thanks to all that helped me achieve a nice table of content!), but as soon as I add chapters, all goes wrong. Please see this example for a good result without chapters:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,parskip]{scrreprt}    
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{tableof}
\AtBeginDocument{\tofOpenTocFileForWrite}

\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{adieresis={ä},germanbls={ß},}

\begin{document}
\part{Erster Teil\\ First Part}

\begin{paracol}{2}
     \centerline{\textbf{Deutsch}}
     \tableoftaggedcontents{d}{}
\switchcolumn
    \centerline{\textbf{English}}
    \tableoftaggedcontents{e}{}
\end{paracol}
%
\begin{paracol}{2}
%\toftagthis{d}
%\chapter{Das erste Kapitel}
Ein bißchen deutscher Text, der das erste Kapitel einleitet, bevor es mit dem
ersten Abschnitt losgeht.
\switchcolumn
%\toftagthis{e}
%\chapter{The first chapter}
A little bit of english text supposed to prepare the reader for the first section.
\switchcolumn
\toftagthis{d}
\section{Der erste Abschnitt im ersten Kapitel}
Der Text zum ersten Abschnitt.
\switchcolumn
\toftagthis{e}
\section{The first section of the first chapter}
Text in the first section.
\toftagthis{d}
\section{Der zweite Abschnitt im ersten Kapitel}
Text im zweiten Abschnitt.
\switchcolumn
\toftagthis{e}
\section{The second section in the first chapter}
Text belonging to the second section.
\end{paracol}
\begin{paracol}{2}
%\toftagthis{d}
%\chapter{Das zweite Kapitel}
\toftagthis{d}
\section{Der erste Abschnitt im zweiten Kapitel}
Das zweite Kapitel beginnt mit diesem Abschnitt.
\switchcolumn
%\toftagthis{e}
%\chapter{The second chapter}
\toftagthis{e}
\section{The first section of the second chapter}
The second chapter starts with this section.
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

And this happens when I add the chapters (by removing the %s):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,parskip]{scrreprt}    
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{tableof}
\AtBeginDocument{\tofOpenTocFileForWrite}

\usepackage{selinput}
\SelectInputMappings{adieresis={ä},germanbls={ß},}

\begin{document}
\part{Erster Teil\\ First Part}

\begin{paracol}{2}
     \centerline{\textbf{Deutsch}}
     \tableoftaggedcontents{d}{}
\switchcolumn
    \centerline{\textbf{English}}
    \tableoftaggedcontents{e}{}
\end{paracol}
%
\begin{paracol}{2}
\toftagthis{d}
\chapter{Das erste Kapitel}
Ein bißchen deutscher Text, der das erste Kapitel einleitet, bevor es mit dem
ersten Abschnitt losgeht.
\switchcolumn
\toftagthis{e}
\chapter{The first chapter}
A little bit of english text supposed to prepare the reader for the first section.
\switchcolumn
\toftagthis{d}
\section{Der erste Abschnitt im ersten Kapitel}
Der Text zum ersten Abschnitt.
\switchcolumn
\toftagthis{e}
\section{The first section of the first chapter}
Text in the first section.
\toftagthis{d}
\section{Der zweite Abschnitt im ersten Kapitel}
Text im zweiten Abschnitt.
\switchcolumn
\toftagthis{e}
\section{The second section in the first chapter}
Text belonging to the second section.
\end{paracol}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\toftagthis{d}
\chapter{Das zweite Kapitel}
\toftagthis{d}
\section{Der erste Abschnitt im zweiten Kapitel}
Das zweite Kapitel beginnt mit diesem Abschnitt.
\switchcolumn
\toftagthis{e}
\chapter{The second chapter}
\toftagthis{e}
\section{The first section of the second chapter}
The second chapter starts with this section.
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

The whole output gets puzzled and the english chapter heading jumps to the left-hand german column.

I tried hard not to mix up the columns, but I cannot see a faulty \switchcolumn or alike. Does anybody know about problems with chapters in **paracol**?

Best regards and many thanks in advance!

tableofconfusion

P.S.: If you answer, take your time, I will be on holidays for two weeks.

Comment: First line got lost, it MUST read:

Comment: DEAR ALL, today...

Comment: I certainly wouldn't have expected that it works. \chapter starts a new page so what should be the result?

Comment: Of course you're right! I overlooked that. But this means that it is virtually impossible to write a book with paracol with chapter captions aligned on top, so I shouldn't use scrbook or scrreprt. Is there an easy way to tell Latex not to start a new page with chapter?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution.

Note that for leftcolumn we need to use `\switchcolumn` and `\flushpage` for rightcolumn.

No clearpage used so floats at the end of chapter may cause problem.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,parskip]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage{mwe}%  just for the example

\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\scr@startchapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\patchcmd\scr@@startchapter{\@topnewpage[\@nameuse{@make#1head}{#3}]}{\@nameuse{@make#1head}{#3}}{}{}
\patchcmd\scr@@startschapter{\@topnewpage[\@nameuse{@makes#1head}{#2}]}{\@nameuse{@makes#1head}{#2}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\chapter{Foo1}
\section{section bar1}
\lipsum

\switchcolumn
\chapter{Foo2}
\section{section bar2}
\lipsum[1]

\flushpage
\chapter{Foo11}
\section{section bar11}

\switchcolumn
\chapter{Foo22}
\section{section bar22}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear touhami, that Looks great! I'll try to implement it in my 100-page document and see what happens with the floats. Thank you!

Comment: Does NOT work for book document class.

Comment: @mmj `\scr@startchapter` is `scr(report,book)` (KOMA-script classes) specific command, it's not defined within standard classes.

Comment: Is it possible to redefine also `\chapter*` in the same way of `\chapter`?

Comment: @mmj i will try :-)

Comment: @mmj you need to add `\patchcmd\scr@@startschapter{\@topnewpage[\@nameuse{@makes#1head}{#2}]}{\@nameuse{@makes#1head}{#2}}{}{}` .

Comment: It seems to work, thanks! Your code allows to use `paracol` at least with `scrbook` document class, since the "chapter clearpage" issue prevents the use of `paracol` with the standard `book` class.