# alignment issue with glbreaking (gloss breaking) in expex

Tags: vertical-alignment, expex, paracol

I have set up a layout using `paracol` with `expex` glosses in one column and regular text in the other column directly across.

At the page break of the MWE below, you can see that the regular-text column does not stay in alignment with the gloss. I have even added and adjusted a special `strut` just for that final paragraph but to no avail (if you adjust the strut so that the regular text moves over to the next page, then it does not come close to aligning properly). Most of the time, the gloss page breaks work just fine, but special cases like this do happen regularly over a long document.

How can the code be adjusted to yield proper alignment, even when this happens at a page break in the middle of a document?

Note: you must use the [latest](https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.2250.1493744151.4791.ctan-ann@ctan.org) `expex` package for the `glbreaking` feature to work.

**MWE (XeTeX):**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[
    paperwidth=7.5in,
    paperheight=9.25in,
    inner=0.5in,
    outer=0.5in,
    bindingoffset=0.25in,
    top=0.75in,
    bottom=1.25in,
    twoside,
    %showframe
    ]
    {geometry} 

\usepackage{paracol}
    \twosided[pc]

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
    \newfontfamily\englishfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{expex}

\lingset{
    everygla=\Large, 
    everyglb=\scriptsize\englishfont\it,
    everyglc=\scriptsize\englishfont,
    glwordalign=center,
    glhangindent=0em,
    glrightskip=0pt,
    glhangstyle=none,
    aboveglbskip=-0.7ex,
    aboveglcskip=-0.7ex,
    glbreaking
}

\columnratio{0.71}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.0em}

\newenvironment{interlinearfirst}%
    {\begin{leftcolumn*}\begin{hebrew}\mystrutfirsta\sloppy\begingl}%
    {\endgl\end{hebrew}\end{leftcolumn*}}
\newenvironment{translationfirst}%
    {\begin{rightcolumn}
    \footnotesize\noindent\ignorespaces\mystrutfirstb\sloppy}
    {\end{rightcolumn}}

\newcommand{\mystrutfirsta}{\rule{0pt}{0pt}}
\newcommand{\mystrutfirstb}{\rule{0pt}{22pt}}

\newenvironment{interlinear}%
    {\begin{leftcolumn*}\begin{hebrew}\mystruta\sloppy\begingl}%
    {\endgl\end{hebrew}\end{leftcolumn*}}
\newenvironment{translation}%
    {\begin{rightcolumn}
    \footnotesize\noindent\ignorespaces\mystrutb\sloppy}
    {\end{rightcolumn}}

\newcommand{\mystruta}{\rule{0pt}{0pt}}
\newcommand{\mystrutb}{\rule{0pt}{12pt}}

\newenvironment{interlinearspecial}%
    {\begin{leftcolumn*}\begin{hebrew}\mystrutc\sloppy\begingl}%
    {\endgl\end{hebrew}\end{leftcolumn*}}
\newenvironment{translationspecial}%
    {\begin{rightcolumn}
    \footnotesize\noindent\ignorespaces\mystrutd\sloppy}
    {\end{rightcolumn}}

\newcommand{\mystrutc}{\rule{0pt}{0pt}}
\newcommand{\mystrutd}{\rule{0pt}{13pt}}%adjust this strut for the last paragraph

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}

\begin{interlinearfirst}
  \gla אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד  //

  \glb aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //

  \glc aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //
\end{interlinearfirst}

\begin{translationfirst}%
Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.
\end{translationfirst}

\begin{interlinear}
  \gla אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד  //

  \glb aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //

  \glc aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //
\end{interlinear}

\begin{translation}%
Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.
\end{translation}

\begin{interlinear}
  \gla אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד  //

  \glb aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //

  \glc aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //
\end{interlinear}

\begin{translation}%
Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.
\end{translation}

\begin{interlinear}
  \gla אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד  //

  \glb aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //

  \glc aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //
\end{interlinear}

\begin{translation}%
Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.
\end{translation}

\begin{interlinear}
  \gla אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד  //

  \glb aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //

  \glc aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //
\end{interlinear}

\begin{translation}%
Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.
\end{translation}

\begin{interlinearspecial}
  \gla אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד  //

  \glb aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //

  \glc aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //
\end{interlinearspecial}

\begin{translationspecial}%
Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.
\end{translationspecial}

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: If  you adjust `\strutd` to 20pt and add a `\flushpage` before the last `translationspecial` doesn't this do what you want? (No need for the `interlinearspecial` it seems.) It's not totally automatic, but can be done once at in the final stages of the document.

Comment: @AlanMunn It works if I put the `\flushpage` before `interlinearspecial` but not `translationspecial`.  That's a good worst case scenario for me, but I would much prefer an automatic solution if possible. Is this a bug in the underlying `expex` package that can be fixed?

Comment: @AlanMunn I'd never seen `flushpage` before actually, and when I searched the site for it I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/331060/121944). Perhaps it's relevant for automating.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. You don't need the `interlinealspecial` though, just the `translationspecial`.  Shall I add this as an answer? Do these bad breaks come up a lot in the document?

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes it comes up a decent amount over a several hundred page document. Sure you can add it as an answer, since it certainly works, but I prefer automation. Also, the `strut` in `interlinearspecial` is set to zero so it shouldn't matter that it's there, right? I just placed it there in case there was ever a need to adjust it.

Comment: Yes, I was just commenting that you don't need two special environments. But I think the problem is with `paracol` not with ExPex. With the `\flushpage` command, the it's the translation paragraph that is too high. The `glbreaking` flag simply puts the gloss lines in a group, and the problem persists even with `glbreaking` set to false.

Comment: @AlanMunn Please submit your answer, even though my preference is an automated solution. I don't want the bounty to go to waste in case no one else answers by the end of the bounty period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is semi-automated solution. The `paracol` package provides a `\flushpage` command to clear the end parallel pair and and start a new page.

This, in conjunction with the `\strut` you've added in the `{translationspecial}` will line up the parallel columns correctly again. (I think the alignment problem is due to `paracol` not ExPex).

Although not totally automatic, I've made things a bit simpler so that you don't need the `special` versions of your environments. Instead I've created a `\flushtrans` command which issues the `\flushpage` command and then sets a conditional to trigger use the right size `\strut` command.

So whenever you have a bad break, issue a `\flushtrans` command before the relevant `{interlinear}` environment, and the rest will happen automatically.

We can use the same technique to eliminate the need for your `translationfirst` and `interlinearfirst` environments. Instead I've added a second conditional which is set at the beginning of a `paracol` environment. This will be used inside the `translation` environment to use the correct strut.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[
    paperwidth=7.5in,
    paperheight=9.25in,
    inner=0.5in,
    outer=0.5in,
    bindingoffset=0.25in,
    top=0.75in,
    bottom=1.25in,
    twoside,
    showframe
    ]
    {geometry} 

\usepackage{paracol}
    \twosided[pc]

\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
    \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
    \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
    \newfontfamily\englishfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{expex}

\lingset{
    everygla=\Large, 
    everyglb=\scriptsize\englishfont\it,
    everyglc=\scriptsize\englishfont,
    glwordalign=center,
    glhangindent=0em,
    glrightskip=0pt,
    glhangstyle=none,
    aboveglbskip=-0.7ex,
    aboveglcskip=-0.7ex,
    glbreaking
}


\columnratio{0.71}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.0em}
\newif\iftranslationspecial
\newif\iffirst
\newcommand\flushtrans{\flushpage\translationspecialtrue}
\AtBeginEnvironment{paracol}{\firsttrue}

\newcommand{\mystrutfirsta}{\rule{0pt}{0pt}}
\newcommand{\mystrutfirstb}{\rule{0pt}{22pt}}

\newenvironment{interlinear}%
    {\begin{leftcolumn*}\begin{hebrew}\mystruta\sloppy\begingl}%
    {\endgl\end{hebrew}\end{leftcolumn*}}

\newenvironment{translation}%
    {\begin{rightcolumn}
\footnotesize\noindent\ignorespaces\iffirst\mystrutfirstb\else\iftranslationspecial\mystrutd\else\mystrutb\fi\fi\sloppy}
    {\end{rightcolumn}\global\translationspecialfalse\global\firstfalse}

\newcommand{\mystruta}{\rule{0pt}{0pt}}
\newcommand{\mystrutb}{\rule{0pt}{12pt}}
\newcommand{\mystrutc}{\rule{0pt}{0pt}}
\newcommand{\mystrutd}{\rule{0pt}{20pt}}%adjust this strut for the last paragraph

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{interlinear}
  \gla אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד  //

  \glb aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //

  \glc aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //
\end{interlinear}

\begin{translation}%
Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.
\end{translation}

\begin{interlinear}
  \gla אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד  //

  \glb aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //

  \glc aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //
\end{interlinear}

\begin{translation}%
Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.
\end{translation}

\begin{interlinear}
  \gla אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד  //

  \glb aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //

  \glc aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //
\end{interlinear}

\begin{translation}%
Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.
\end{translation}

\begin{interlinear}
  \gla אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד  //

  \glb aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //

  \glc aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //
\end{interlinear}

\begin{translation}%
Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.
\end{translation}

\begin{interlinear}
  \gla אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד  //

  \glb aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //

  \glc aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //
\end{interlinear}

\begin{translation}%
Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.
\end{translation}
\flushtrans % added this

\begin{interlinear}
  \gla אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד  //

  \glb aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //

  \glc aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //
\end{interlinear}

\begin{translation}%
Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.
\end{translation}
\begin{interlinear}
  \gla אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד אאאאא בבבבב גגגגג דדדדד  //

  \glb aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //

  \glc aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd aaaaa bbbbb ggggg ddddd //
\end{interlinear}

\begin{translation}%
Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.
\end{translation}

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image: partial output of code]

Comment: I'm clear on everything except how you are calling up `translationspecial` when you got rid if it. That is, you have `if`, `true`, and `false`, but there is no `translationspecial` environment anymore. How does that work?

Comment: @AML The only difference between your `translation` and `translationspecial` environments was whether you used `\strutb` or `\strutd`. So the conditional changes which strut gets used. Whenever you issue the `\flushtrans` command, it sets the conditional to use `\strutd`. At the end of the environment the flag is set back so that subsequent uses will use `\strutb` until another `\flushtrans` command is issued.

Comment: @AML I've now edited to do the same for the `...first` environments, which are no longer needed.

Comment: ahhh, now I get. Thanks for the explanation.